# Tensorflow label_image NotFoundError after retraining

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, pre-trained-model

I've run the tensoflow's `retrain.py` script on my custom dataset. After the training process I got the expected output files `output_graph.pb` and `output_labels.txt`. 
However, when I tried to predict the label on an unseen image by using the latest tensorflow's `label_image.py` script I got this error:

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Error while reading resource variable module/InceptionV3/Mixed_7c/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_mean from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/module/InceptionV3/Mixed_7c/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_mean)
         [[Node: import/module_apply_default/InceptionV3/InceptionV3/Mixed_7c/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm/ReadVariableOp = ReadVariableOp[dtype=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](import/module/InceptionV3/Mixed_7c/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_mean)]]
```

Does anyone have an idea, why some variables might be incorrectly initialized?